# Remove values using condition from multidimensional array using java-script

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array as following.

```
[['Base: Values','55','98','90.8'],['Value First','55','98','90.8'],['Top','55','98','90.8'],['Bottom','55','98','90.8']]
```

I want to remove entire values if it includes 'Top' or 'Bottom', so that i will get a result like this:

```
[['Base: Values','55','98','90.8'],['Value First','55','98','90.8']]
```

Somebody give me a solution please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the array, providing a function to determine if an element should be included or not :

```
array.filter(e => !e.includes('Top') && !e.includes('Bottom'));
```

Example:

```js
const data = [
    ['Base: Values','55','98','90.8'],
    ['Value First','55','98','90.8'],
    ['Top','55','98','90.8'],
    ['Bottom','55','98','90.8']
]
const filtered = data.filter(e => !e.includes('Top') && !e.includes('Bottom'));
console.log(filtered)
console.log(data)
```

**EDIT**: To exclude if any string in array values contains a specific part, you could change the predicate to check if at least one string contains the part:

```
array.filter(e => !e.some(i => i.includes('part to find')));
```

Example:

```js
const data = [
    ['Base: Values','55','98','90.8'],
    ['Value First','55','98','90.8'],
    ['Top','55','98','90.8'],
    ['Bottom','55','98','90.8']
]
const filtered = data.filter(e => !e.some(i => i.includes('Value')));
console.log(filtered)
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its working fine if i am checking exact word. What i have to do to remove by checking a portion only. In the above example if i want to delete ['Base: Values','55','98','90.8'] by checking 'Base ' only??